# "Almost Pretty" Permalink can't work for my Wordpress website on IIS 6

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I'm running WordPress Version 3.5.1 on Windows 2003 Server IIS6 and PHP5. I've managed to create a test site. However, when I tried to use Permalinks, I'm unable to get it to work other than the elementary default http://www.mydomain.com/?p=123

I've spent 2 days trying to figure out and searching google, tried every solution I found online for both "almost pretty" (Pathinfo) and "pretty" permalinks, but failed.  At the minimum, I need "Almost Pretty" permalinks to work - http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#PATHINFO:_.22Almost_Pretty.22

```
http://mydomain.com/index.php/post-name/
```

For "almost pretty" permalink, I've added the lines to PHP.ini:

```
cgi.fix_pathinfo=1
cgi.force_redirect=0
```

PATHINFO is working on my server, I've tested with something like http://www.mydomain.com/phpinfo.php/HELLO_THERE and it works.

However, http://mydomain.com/index.php/post-name/ doesn't work.

I've also tried the 404 method as described here- http://anaestrada81.wordpress.com/2008/10/03/almost-pretty-permalinks-for-wordpress-and-iis6-and-front-page/

The method also requires .htaccess file to be server writable. However, I can't find the .htaccess file in the root directory of Wordpress. I don't want what this file should contain. I've tried adding the sample file in http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Creating_and_editing_.28.htaccess.29 and assigned total control rights to "everyone". After this, resetting the permanlink settings don't appear to update the .htaccess file so I'm not sure if this file is needed in the first place.

Will appreciate any help.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an update.  I found a solution on a blog, by using a 404 redirect php file. More info here - http://ikailo.com/94/url-modrewrite-workaround-iis-60/comment-page-1/#comments